# cudaMalloc failing After Several Hours

Tags: memory-management, cuda

Is there any reason why cudaMalloc fails to allocate memory when running a gpu code for 2-3 hours?
I am using a "Process Explorer" program to check the global memory usage. Suddenly cudaMalloc fails to allocate although free global memory on the gpu is still available.

How can i check the main reason of this failure? i am doing this:

```
if ( cudaSuccess !=cudaMalloc((void **) &arr, sizeof(int)*100)) 
    printf("Cannot Allocate Mem");
```

is there a better way to print the actual reason of the failure in cuda?

Comment: If you really have free memory on the GPU (how do you know this?), one possible explanation is memory fragmentation.  The allocation in your example is so small, though, that it seems odd that it would cause failures in a fragmented situation.  In any case, if you can restructure your code to "hold onto" allocations and reduce the number of calls to cudaMalloc()/cudaFree(), that would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do below:

```
cudaError_t err= cudaMalloc((void **) &arr, sizeof(int)*100);
if(err != cudaSuccess){
     printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
}
```

This will print the exact reason of the error. Eg. invalid device pointer means you are accessing a pointer that does not point to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the **`cudaMalloc` output against the status variable `cudaSuccess`**. For a minimal working example see below, remember to be environmental friendly and free the space!

```cpp
// nvcc device_query.cu -o device_query; ./device_query

#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    int *arr;
    cudaError_t err= cudaMalloc((void **) &arr, sizeof(int)*1024*1024*1024*10);
    if(err != cudaSuccess){
        printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    cudaFree( arr );
}
```

Because of intentionally excessive allocation this gives

```
root@38c6fcde90a4:/home/zkp/cuZK/test# nvcc device_query.cu -o device_query; ./device_query
The error is out of memory
```

This example is essentially a recipe from the great book "CUDA by Example" with [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/chris-ricketts/cuda-by-example/blob/master/common/book.h#L21-L29).

---

Even better, **include book recipes into your code**. The same example now becomes:

```cpp
// nvcc device_query.cu -o device_query; ./device_query

#include <stdio.h> 
#include "../cuda-by-example/common/book.h" // download locally and reference accordingly

int main() {
    int *arr;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void **) &arr, sizeof(int)*1024*1024*1024*10) );
    cudaFree( arr );
}
```

and runs as

```
root@82c2bdcd5ad8:/home/cuZK# ./device_query
out of memory in device_query.cu at line 8
```